# Dynamically importing repository after running setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

### The Problem

I have a Python script that runs in the background. At some point the script tries to import a module: `import mymodule`.

Before the import line is executed in the Python script, another bash script (successfully) installs `mymodule` by running `python setup.py install`.

The problem is that `import mymodule` in the Python script is not working because `mymodule` is not found, even though it's installed.

### My solution

I checked `sys.path` before installing `mymodule` and after I saw that a new line had been added: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mymodule-1.0py.egg`. So before the line importing the module I added the line `sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mymodule-1.0py.egg")`.

My question is whether there is a better, less hardcoded way to solve the problem.

Comment: Oops, I missed capitalisation of "solution" in second header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to refresh the sys.path
but you can use the site.py to do it.

```
import site 
reload(site)
```